Problems with selecting OptunaSearchCV pipeline parameters
I have a code with which I iterate over the hyperparameters of both the model itself and the entire pipeline
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
            [
                ('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary', sparse_output=False), binary_cols),
                ('CatBoostEncoder', CatBoostEncoder(random_state=RANDOM_STATE), non_binary_cat_cols),
                ('StandardScaler', StandardScaler(), num_cols)
            ],
            verbose_feature_names_out=False,
            remainder='drop'
        )
    
        pipe_final = ImbPipeline([
            ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
            ('target_imbalance', ADASYN()),
            ('selection', PCA()),
            ('models', CatBoostClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE))
        ])

        # Гиперпараметры для CatBoostClassifier
        param_grid = {
            'models__iterations': [1000, 2000, 3000],
            'models__class_weights': ['Balanced', None],
            'target_imbalance': [ADASYN(random_state=RANDOM_STATE), SMOTETomek(random_state=RANDOM_STATE),
                                 SMOTE(random_state=RANDOM_STATE, k_neighbors=10), 'passthrough'],
            'preprocessor__StandardScaler': [StandardScaler(), RobustScaler(), MinMaxScaler(),
                                             PowerTransformer(), QuantileTransformer(),
                                             Normalizer(),PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False), 'passthrough'],
            'selection': [PCA(random_state=RANDOM_STATE, n_components="mle", svd_solver="full"),
                          SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=40),
                          SelectKBest(f_classif, k=40),
                          SelectKBest(chi2, k=40),
                          SelectPercentile(mutual_info_classif, percentile=10),
                          SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=10),
                          SelectFromModel(CatBoostClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)),
                          SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)),
                          SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)),
                          'passthrough'],
        }

        gs = GridSearchCV(
            pipe_final, 
            param_grid, 
            cv=5, 
            scoring='roc_auc', 
            n_jobs=-1
        )

        # Запускаем поиск гиперпараметров
        gs.fit(X, y_enc)

It takes a very long time to complete and I want to speed it up. For this I want to use OptunaSearchCV. Do I understand correctly that using OptunaSearchCV I can enumerate the hyperparameters of the model itself, but not the entire pipeline, because Is there no Distribution with which I can set SelectKBest(f_classif, k=40), RobustScaler(), etc.?
Sorry if my wording is not accurate somewhere, I use Google translator, because... I am not a native speaker

Optuna says it requires an Optuna Distribution object for each hyperparameter's "range".  But there is CategoricalDistribution for providing a discrete list of options.  There is the Note in the documentation though which might indicate an issue in some settings:

Not all types are guaranteed to be compatible with all storages. It is recommended to restrict the types of the choices to None, bool, int, float and str.


I first interpreted your question to be about setting the hyperparameters of steps in a pipeline, so the convention like preprocessor__StandardScaler.  I no longer thing that's what you meant, but in case others come here with that confusion:
In the documentation of OptunaSearchCV, the estimator parameter is explained as "Object to use to fit the data. This is assumed to implement the scikit-learn estimator interface. [...]", and I would assume that means they use clone and set_params to create an estimator for each hyperparameter setting; then it should be fine to use a pipeline with the usual naming convention for steps' hyperparameters.

Thank you very much for the answer. The whole problem is that if you directly set this in the same way as in GridSearchCV, the following error will appear
CategoricalDistribution(['Balanced', None]),             'target_imbalance': CategoricalDistribution([ADASYN, SMOTETomek,SMOTE, "passthrough"])
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\optuna\distributions.py:524: UserWarning: Choices for a categorical distribution should be a tuple of None, bool, int, float and str for persistent storage but contains ADASYN(random_state=42) which is of type ADASYN.

But that's just a warning, not an error. Does the optimization proceed, and can you extract scores? (Are they different across these object-hyperparameters?) I haven't used Optuna much, but tried this (but it seemed too long for a comment).
